# How to hookup a Cloud Function for Google Identity Platform's beforeSignIn event via Terraform?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-identity

I want to setup a cloud function via Terraform for `beforeSignIn` event in Google Identity Platform.  [Google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/blocking-functions#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the,in%20(beforeSignIn).) explains how to do this manually as shown in [this screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2083321/214149900-17ae0b2a-898b-464a-b8b3-60b78862208a.png).

My question is, **How to do this via Terraform**?

I couldn't find anything in *Google Identity* configuration side ([google_identity_platform_project_default_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/identity_platform_project_default_config)). So I thought this should be configured from the *Cloud Functions* side, and I tried to use [event_trigger](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_function.html#nested_event_trigger) when creating the function as follows via terraform:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {

  // ...  

  event_trigger {
    event_type = "providers/cloud.auth/eventTypes/user.beforeSignIn:password"
    resource = projects/<my-project-id>
  }
}
```

But I'm getting *400 Bad Request* from Google when trying to terraform apply with the following message:

> Unknown event_type providers/cloud.auth/eventTypes/user.beforeSignIn:password

This error makes sense because this event is not in the supported event types in cloud functions. *You can get all the supported event types list from `gcloud functions event-types list` command (example output [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2083321/214155136-c0284dd3-c4f0-497c-ace8-0119332d81ce.png))*.